# Snakemake: Parameter as wildcard used in parallel script runs

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

I'm fairly new to snakemake and inherited a kind of huge worflow that consists in a sequence of 17 rules that run in serial.
Each rule takes outputs from the previous rules and uses them to run a python script. Everything has worked great so far except that now I'm trying to improve the worflow since some of the rules can be run in parallel.

A rough example of what I'm trying to achieve, my understanding is  that wildcards should allow me to solve this.

```snakemake
grid = [ 10 , 20 ]

rule all:
input:
    expand("path/to/C/{grid}/file_C" ,grid = grid)

rule process_A:
input:
    path_A = "path/to/A/file_A"
    path_B = "path/to/B/{grid}/file_B" # A rule further in the worflow could need a file from a previous rule saved with this structure
params:
    grid = lambda wc: wc.get(grid)
output:
    path_C = "path/to/C/{grid}/file_C"
script:
    "script_A.py"
```

And inside the script I retrieve the grid size parameter:

```python
grid = snakemake.params.grid
```

In the end the whole rule process_A should be rerun with grid = 10 and with grid = 20 and save each result to a folder whose path depends on grid also.

I know there are several things wrong with this, but I can't seem to find were to start from to figure this out. The error I'm getting now is:

```
name 'params' is not defined
```

Any help as to where to start from?

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to post the error stack trace of `name 'params' is not defined` to know exactly what is causing it. For now...

> And inside the script I retrieve the grid size parameter:
>
> grid = snakemake.params.grid

I suspect you are mixing the [script](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts) directive with the shell directive. Probably you want something like:

```
rule process_A:
    input: ...
    output: ...
    params: ...
    script:
        "script_A.py"
```

inside `script_A.py` snakemake will replace  `snakemake.params.grid` with the actual param value.

Alternatively, write a standalone python script that parses command line arguments and you execute like any other program using the `shell` directive. (I tend to prefer this solution as it makes things more explicit and easier to debug but it also means more boiler-plate code to write a standalone script).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed, script instead of shell works better. I managed to get a simple version to run, the main issue I was having was an expand function on my output not parsing the wildcards correctly.